# PHP: How to count same values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to count the same values of DIAGNOSA at the  array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [NIK_PASIEN] => 6005
        [DIAGNOSA] => ["Hipertensi","ISPA"]
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [NIK_PASIEN] => 6163
        [DIAGNOSA] => ["ISPA"]
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [NIK_PASIEN] => 5853
        [DIAGNOSA] => ["Hipertensi","ISPA","Vertigo"]
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [NIK_PASIEN] => 5613
        [DIAGNOSA] => ["Vertigo"]
    )
)
```

How to make it will convert to array like following?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [DIAGNOSA] => ISPA
        [COUNT] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [DIAGNOSA] => Hipertensi
        [COUNT] => 2
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [DIAGNOSA] => Vertigo
        [COUNT] => 2
    )
)
```

and I will display it in the following table:

| DIAGNOSA | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| ISPA | 3 |
| Hipertensi | 2 |
| Vertigo | 2 |

How should I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this piece of code!

```
$array = [
            ['NIK_PASIEN'=>6005,'DIAGNOSA'=>["Hipertensi","ISPA"]],
            ['NIK_PASIEN'=>6163,'DIAGNOSA'=>["ISPA"]],
            ['NIK_PASIEN'=>5853,'DIAGNOSA'=>["Hipertensi","ISPA","Vertigo"]],
            ['NIK_PASIEN'=>5613,'DIAGNOSA'=>["Vertigo"]],
        ];

$detailed = [];
    foreach ($array as $ar) {
        foreach ($ar['DIAGNOSA'] as $key) {
            $original_key = array_search($key, array_column($detailed, 'DIAGNOSA'), true);
            if ($original_key !== false) {
                $detailed[$original_key]['COUNT'] += 1;
            } else {
                $temp['DIAGNOSA'] = $key;
                $temp['COUNT'] = 1;
                $detailed[] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

the result will be in detailed array

Comment: Thank you so much @Sterko , you are so great.

Comment: @AsyahSinaga you are welcome, mark as correct this answer!